# Azure DevOps Pipeline - How to run Kotlin script - *.kts files

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-script

To run a [Kotlin script](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/command-line.html#run-scripts) one needs to execute:

```
kotlinc -script myScript.kts
```

Do I need to download the [Kotlin command-line compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/command-line.html#homebrew) to have access to it, or there is an easier way?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @ADroid yeah, answered below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kotlin scripting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/custom-script-deps-tutorial.html) is the solution to this problem, but it is still experimental, and it didn't work for me very well.

I ended up using [Gradle Kotlin DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html). Here is a nice [samples](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples) repo to get you started fast.